# Problems getting error message from AJAX - error on phone only

Tags: ajax, error-handling

I have a basic web app - it is bug free for a while.
Occasionally - for what I expect is some network issue, I am unsure - 
And only on a phone (Android / chrome) - The basic AJAX returns an error - but there is no value.

This is driving me a bit crazy - as I do not know how to debug an error that is blank.

Basic AJAX post:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+controller_G+"/"+Method_Param_G+"?"+Math.random()+"&SEARCH_STRING="+SEARCH_STRING_G, $("#"+Data_G).serialize(), function(data, status){
}).done(function(data){

    // OWNER SEARCH VIA APP
    if(data.indexOf("Search term found:") > -1){
        // Happy Days! :)
    }
}).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $("#ajax_message").modal();
    $("#ajax_error_message_inner_text").html(textStatus+" -> "+errorThrown+" -> "+xhr.responseText);
});
```

The **ajax_message** produces "**error -> -> undefined**"

I can not replicate this error in my desktop browser chrome - all seems fine there.

Would also be helpful to know:
What are the typical ways to debug in android/iphone anyway?
And what are the typical errors with AJAX on a phone?

When I reload the page on the phone - normal operation returns for a while.
eventually another error returns.

Comment: Sorry - I messed up the first time - the question has been adjusted

Answer (score 0):

Error event don`t have "xhr, status, error" params.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+controller_G+"/"+Method_Param_G+"?"+Math.random(),
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){
  // Happy days :)
},
error: function(jqXHR, exception){

    var msg = "";
    console.log(jqXHR);

    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }

    console.log(msg);
}});
```

Comment: Sorry - I messed up and added the wrong code the first time - it is still similar - can not get an error message that is meaningful

Answer (score 0):

Debug the app using chrome developer tools. Go through this [Link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)

After setup the Ajax Error can then be seen in Network tab just like any other normal web debugging.